# Why is this mildly subjective Minecraft question getting downvoted?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, subjective

Today a question was asked on Arqade: [What is the hardest block to obtain in Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/375310/what-is-the-hardest-block-to-obtain-in-minecraft)

I think this is definitely one of the more fun and interesting [minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft) questions of the past few weeks. It reminded me of old classics like 'What's the best mining strategy', etc. It has 2 downvotes, 0 up (not counting me).

I don't think anything's wrong with the question. I know that questions shouldn't be primarily opinion-based, and I called the question 'mildly subjective' in the title, but that isn't the primary focus of the question, and to be honest I put that in the title just so this post isn't another 'What's wrong with this question' meta post.

Also it doesn't help that the question was asked by a user named DREADLORD_XD with under 100 points, but still.

So why did the downvoters downvote? Or were they wrong?

Comment: I think it's just a bad question.  Simple as that.

Comment: ""It's just a bad question""

Comment: The question poses an interesting topic, but - in my opinion - it's too broad at the moment. It needs some definition as to what 'hardness' means to the OP. I wrote [this comment](//arqade.com/q/375310#comment526835_375310) requesting some extra parameters.

Answer (score 8):

It isn't mildly subjective, it's very subjective.  The answers not coming to much agreement is an indicator of that.  What does "hardest" mean?  Time consuming?  Risk of death?  Something else?  Does a beacon count separately from an activated beacon?  If so, do the blocks under the beacon matter?  It is under-specified and doesn't have a "right" answer, as far as I see.

Comment: Having many different answers isn't necessarily a bad thing. Even on a question like this there are wrong answers. If you look at the first 2, they both talk about something that is close to the most correct answer, yet I come up with something even better in my answer, because I put more thought into it. Yet SF went all out and came up with the best answer (and I think we can all agree on that). Perhaps the question should be worded 'What are some of the hardest blocks to obtain'. At the end of the day, I think it's opinion-based to decide whether the question is subjective haha

Comment: I'd say let's leave it as is and not create a long discussion before it gets too subjective :) 

(I ran out of comment space on my previous comment, sorry for double notification)

Answer (score -3):

I was an answerer on the question, and yes, I have to agree it was kind of subjective, however I, like most people, inferred that he meant rarest. So he
expected us to know what he meant.